# how to center image inside a rect pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to centre an image inside a rect note that I am using the image rect but  asseperate rect to mount the image on.

```
rect_1 = pygame.Rect(1, 1, 178, 178)
...
cross = pygame.image.load("cross.png").convert_alpha()
cross_minified = pygame.transform.rotozoom(cross, 0, 0.25)
...
screen.blit(cross_minified, rect_1)
```

and after these codes I cannot find a way to center my x to the middle of the rect_1
it looks somewhat like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the functionality of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). Get a rectangle with the size of the image by [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) and set its center by the keyword argument `center` from the center of `rect_1`:

```py
cross_rect = cross_minified.get_rect(center = rect_1.center)
screen.blit(cross_minified, cross_rect)
```